# Default value can be assigned for forms.DecimalField? Is it has to be already assigned in model declaration?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Wherever I try to give a default value to this field, which is supposed to be outside of my model gives error saying "default" or "attr" argument is unexpected.

```
    log_duration_minute = forms.DecimalField(
        help_text=_("log_duration_helper_text_minute"),
        default="0.00",
    )
```

---

The error message:

```
    __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'
```

Comment: Can you post the whole form please? Not just 1 field on a form. Thanks.

Comment: I was unsure about the privacy of the work I'm on, the error was given only due to this field. Thank you I'll be sure to give more details about the problem next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use default values in the model, but when defining a form field use `initial =`

You may also want to

```
from decimal import Decimal
```

so that you can use

```
initial = Decimal('0.00')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was thinking that only number inputs take initial argument instead of default. Now I see it is because of the form declaration style.